# Exclude All Tags Except One - XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to fetch all `HTTPSamplerProxy` tags with all its children but donot want any extra text/tag.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="3.2" jmeter="3.2 r1790748">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup enabled="true">
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <intProp name="LoopController.loops">1</intProp>
        </elementProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <GenericController guiclass="LogicControllerGui" testname="1 /index.html" enabled="true"/>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="1 /index.html" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">webforumtestsolutions.co.uk</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">0</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/index.html</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
                <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
              </collectionProp>
            </elementProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp reference="../../../HTTPSamplerProxy/elementProp[2]/collectionProp"/>
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
        <GenericController guiclass="LogicControllerGui" testname="2 /index.html" enabled="true"/>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="2 /index.html" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">webforumtestsolutions.co.uk</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">0</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/index.html</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
                <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
              </collectionProp>
            </elementProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp reference="../../../HTTPSamplerProxy/elementProp[2]/collectionProp"/>
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
        <GenericController guiclass="LogicControllerGui" testname="3 /toolsets.html" enabled="true"/>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="3 /toolsets.html" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">webforumtestsolutions.co.uk</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">0</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/toolsets.html</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
                <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
              </collectionProp>
            </elementProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp reference="../../../HTTPSamplerProxy/elementProp[2]/collectionProp"/>
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
        <GenericController guiclass="LogicControllerGui" testname="4 /internet-of-things.html" enabled="true"/>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="4 /internet-of-things.html" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">webforumtestsolutions.co.uk</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">0</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/internet-of-things.html</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
                <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
              </collectionProp>
            </elementProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp reference="../../../HTTPSamplerProxy/elementProp[2]/collectionProp"/>
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
        <GenericController guiclass="LogicControllerGui" testname="5 /services.html" enabled="true"/>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="5 /services.html" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">webforumtestsolutions.co.uk</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">0</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/services.html</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
                <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
              </collectionProp>
            </elementProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp reference="../../../HTTPSamplerProxy/elementProp[2]/collectionProp"/>
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
        <GenericController guiclass="LogicControllerGui" testname="6 /contact-us.html" enabled="true"/>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="6 /contact-us.html" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">webforumtestsolutions.co.uk</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">0</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/contact-us.html</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
                <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
              </collectionProp>
            </elementProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp reference="../../../HTTPSamplerProxy/elementProp[2]/collectionProp"/>
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
        <GenericController guiclass="LogicControllerGui" testname="7 /test-planning.html" enabled="true"/>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="7 /test-planning.html" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">webforumtestsolutions.co.uk</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">0</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/test-planning.html</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
                <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
              </collectionProp>
            </elementProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp reference="../../../HTTPSamplerProxy/elementProp[2]/collectionProp"/>
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:variable name="doc-file">http://mymachine.com/changed.xml</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="//HTTPSamplerProxy">
   <xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
  false
  false
      false
      1





      <HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
          <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">webforumtestsolutions.co.uk</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">0</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/index.html</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager"
            elementType="HeaderManager"
            guiclass="HeaderPanel"
            testclass="HeaderManager"
            testname="HTTP Header Manager"
            enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
            <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
          </collectionProp>
        </elementProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
      </HTTPSamplerProxy>


... Other <HTTPSamplerProxy></HTTPSamplerProxy> tags
```

You can try it [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html). I just donot want `false` and `1` in my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="//HTTPSamplerProxy"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The result will not have a root element containing the copied elements, meaning it will not be a well-formed document if you have several elements to copy.

Comment: Can you explain a bit that why my solution wasn't working ?

Comment: You have written a template for the `HTTPSamplerProxy` that copies them but processing usually starts at the document node and if your stylesheet has no matching template(s) then the built-in ones https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule are used, that way the child nodes and descendant nodes are processed recursively where the built-in templates copy text nodes through. So that is why you see that text data.